# Why does native element local reference doesnt work inside ngx-slick-carousel

Tags: angular

I just want to check which slide is currently showing so that I could add some text animation to the currently active image. In ngx slider it adds slick-active or current class to the currently active slider.

I put a local `galleryOne` and tried to check it with viewchild and element ref but it gives the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

The same thing if i do outside of the ngx-slick-carousel selector then no issues.

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel"  class="lazy slider" 
          #slickModal="slick-carousel" #galleryOne [config]="slideConfig"
          >
            <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
              <h1>{{slide.txt}}</h1>
              <figure><img src="{{slide.img}}" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
            </div>
          </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('galleryOne') galleryOne: ElementRef;
     slides = [
        {img: "theme/images/home01.jpg", txt: 'dsfsdfsdfsdfsdf'},
        {img: "theme/images/home02.jpg", txt: 'sdddddddddddddddddd'},
        {img: "theme/images/home03.jpg", txt: 'dsfdsffffffffffffffffffsfsdf'}
      ]
      slideConfig = {autoplay: true,"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1, speed:800, "autoplaySpeed": 3000, cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.250,  0.060, 0.050, 0.040)'};

     ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.galleryOne.nativeElement.classList.hasClass('slick-active'));
```

Comment: you need to check the classList in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:
The galleryOne ElementRef is only correctly defined in AfterViewInit lifecyclehook

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('galleryOne') galleryOne: ElementRef;
     slides = [
        {img: "theme/images/home01.jpg", txt: 'dsfsdfsdfsdfsdf'},
        {img: "theme/images/home02.jpg", txt: 'sdddddddddddddddddd'},
        {img: "theme/images/home03.jpg", txt: 'dsfdsffffffffffffffffffsfsdf'}
      ]
      slideConfig = {autoplay: true,"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1, speed:800, "autoplaySpeed": 3000, cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.250,  0.060, 0.050, 0.040)'};

     ngOnInit() {

     }

     ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.galleryOne.nativeElement.classList.hasClass('slick-active'));
     }
}
```